# Longest common subsequence of two permutations

Tags: algorithms

Given two permutations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ of numbers $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$,
can we find $\mathrm{LCS}(\pi_1,\pi_2)$ in $O(n\log n)$? I think we can use LIS but I get stuck.

Comment: Find the LIS of $\pi_1$ with $\pi_2[a]\prec \pi_2[b]$.

Comment: @JohnL. Could you explain your idea?

Comment: A subsequence of $\pi_1$ is $\pi_1(j_1),\ldots,\pi_1(j_m)$, where $j_1 < \cdots < j_m$. It is also a subsequence of $\pi_2$ if the indices of its elements in $\pi_2$ is also increasing, i.e., $\pi_2^{-1}(\pi_1(j_1)) < \cdots < \pi_2^{-1}(\pi_1(j_m))$. So you want to find the LIS of $\pi_2^{-1}\pi_1$.

Comment: The notations used in my comment above are copied from Yuval's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence $i_1,\ldots,i_m$ is a common sequence if $\pi_1^{-1}(i_1) < \cdots < \pi_1^{-1}(i_m)$ and $\pi_2^{-1}(i_1) < \cdots < \pi_2^{-1}(i_m)$.

A sequence $j_1,\ldots,j_m$ is such that $\pi_1(j_1),\ldots,\pi_1(j_m)$ is a common sequence if $j_1 < \cdots < j_m$ and $\pi_2^{-1}(\pi_1(j_1)) < \cdots < \pi_2^{-1}(\pi_1(j_m))$.

We conclude that the longest common sequence of $\pi_1,\pi_2$ is the longest increasing sequence of $\pi_2^{-1}\pi_1$.

Comment: What is $\pi^{-1}$?

Comment: The inverse of $\pi$, defined by $\pi^{-1}(i)=j$ iff $\pi(j)=i$.